# Bose-Einstein Condensate

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

In lieu of recent research showing the possibility of obtaining the Bose-Einstein condensate Nq, in certain polymers is there any statistical mechanical way of figuring out the frequency with which the condensate would happen at random in say certain small regions of space with high gravitational fields ie stars, black holes? Can MKT/2pih^2 be represented using statistical mechanics by simply isolating Boltzman's constant under a set of restraints? Trying to find a way to approach this problem mathematically with a background in only physical chemistry is challenging. Thanks.  J. Gray